# How can I change the color and pattern of each line for the "death from cancer" and "death other causes" in the ggcuminc?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, ggsurvfit

I want to change the color and pattern of each line for the "death from cancer" (solid and red) and "death other causes" (solid and blue) competing outcomes for the entire cohort (not stratified by trt or any other group) on the plot below, but I can't change them.

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(tidycmprsk) 
library(ggsurvfit)

custom_colors <- c("yellow", "blue") # Add more colors as needed

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ 1, trial) %>%

ggcuminc(outcome = c("death from cancer","death other causes")) +

add_confidence_interval() +

add_risktable(size = 4, theme = theme_risktable_default(axis.text.y.size = 12, plot.title.size = 12)) +

theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20), axis.text = element_text(size = 15), legend.text = element_text(size = 15)) +

scale_color_manual(values = custom_colors) # Set custom line colors
```

This code does not do what I expect to do.

[image: Cummulative incidence plot]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to take advantage of a new feature available in the development version of the package. See example below. Happy Programming!

```r
devtools::install_github("pharmaverse/ggsurvfit")
#> Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
#> Skipping install of 'ggsurvfit' from a github remote, the SHA1 (28cc0e02) has not changed since last install.
#>   Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
packageVersion("ggsurvfit")
#> [1] '0.3.1.9002'
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

# review `?ggsurvfit_options` for details on this option
options("ggsurvfit.switch-color-linetype" = TRUE)

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ 1, trial) %>%
  ggcuminc(outcome = c("death from cancer", "death other causes")) +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable(size = 4, theme = theme_risktable_default(axis.text.y.size = 12, plot.title.size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20), axis.text = element_text(size = 15), legend.text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow", "blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow", "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! How would you change the line pattern?

Comment: For this option you select between using linetype or color `aes()` for the outcomes, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `1` with the group (here: `trt`) Then your code should work as expected. I changed yellow with red:

```
#install.packages("tidycmprsk")
library(ggplot2) 
library(tidycmprsk) 
library(ggsurvfit)
library(dplyr)


custom_colors <- c("red", "blue") # Add more colors as needed

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) %>% # Stratify by trt
  ggcuminc(outcome = c("death from cancer", "death other causes")) +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable(size = 4, theme = theme_risktable_default(axis.text.y.size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 15), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = custom_colors) # Set custom line colors
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without stratifying by trt group and leave that as ~1? I am trying to solve this issue for another dataset I have for which I cannot stratify by group.

Comment: I am not sure, what you are trying to do. In your code there is a stratification in ggcuminc(outcome = c("death from cancer","death other causes")), but this does not work with ~1 which indicates estimates for the total cohort. Anyway changing the colors for the total cohort seems to be not easy with tidycmprsk.

Comment: Please reread my question above. I made some changes to make it more clear. I hope you can help.